# Java functions become undefined inside Matlab class

Tags: java, matlab, class, oop, import

Im getting started with OOP in matlab. However using java objects in my code causes me quite a bit of a headache.
Specifically I run into this error when I try to run testClass.start():

> Undefined function 'SessionSettings' for input arguments of type
>   'char'.

The mentioned function is present in the jar which gets imported and the code is running fine if it's run outside of a matlab class.
here's the class:

```
classdef testClass

 properties
     data
 end

 methods

      function obj = testClass()
         % class constructor
         javaaddpath /home/test/test-examples-1.5.3.jar;
         import test.examples.thingy.*;

      end


     function ret = start()
         % 
         settings = sessionSettings('configFilePath');
      end
 end

end
```

Comment: It looks like it tries to find a method named `SessionSettings(char arg1)` which does not exist in your jar. Maybe it takes a `String`?

Comment: the method actually exists in the jar, and if I run the above code outside of a class, then it works. Ie. just running:

javaaddpath /home/test/test-examples-1.5.3.jar;

import test.examples.thingy.*;

settings = sessionSettings('configFilePath'); 

works

Comment: similar question: [importing java classes in matlab classdef](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16407337/97160)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing the documentation of [`import()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/import.html):

> The import function only affects the import list of the function
>   within which it is used. When invoked at the command prompt, import
>   uses the import list for the MATLAB® command environment. If import is
>   used in a script invoked from a function, it affects the import list
>   of the function. If import is used in a script that is invoked from
>   the command prompt, it affects the import list for the command
>   environment.
>
> The import list of a function is persistent across calls to that
>   function and is only cleared when the function is cleared.

This means, that your method `start()` will see an empty import list.